# How is the Pythagorean Theorem related to the Equation of a Circle

Tags: geometry

My teacher wants me to figure out how the Pythagorean Theorem and the Equation of a Circle are related. I can't figure this out because I view them as being two completely different things. I understand what the equation for a circle is, but how does that relate to the Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: Draw a circle with radius $r$ and center at the origin. In polar coordinates, $x=r\sin \theta,y=r\cos\theta$. $x^2+y^2=1$ is thus true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a circle with radius $r$ and center at the origin. In polar coordinates, $x=r\sin \theta,y=r\cos\theta$. $x^2+y^2=1$ is thus true.

The equation for a circle is $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$. You can use the following diagram:
[image]

(From https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/circle-equations.html.)

Answer (score 0):

$$(x−a)^2+(y−b)^2=r^2$$

Look at the equation of a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$.

Consider the right triangle with sides $A = x-a, B = y-b$ and $C = r$.
You  see that the equation of the circle is just the Pythagorean theorem.